# How do I run a group of nodes together with Dask

Tags: dask, dask-distributed, dask-delayed

I have an image processing graph and I want to process many images in batch. My graph looks like the following:
[image: My graph made from delayed functions]

When I run the graph bokeh shows the execution path like this:
[image: How I observe it to run in bokeh]

This causes my machines to run out of memory and crash as the output of the load image is megabytes of images. I would like the graph to run like this as as the result of Save result is very small and should be fine:
[image: How I want it to run in bokeh]

How can I do this with dask?

[Customizing Optimization](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/optimize.html#customizing-optimization) seems like it would be useful where I could possibly fuse the middle nodes. Is this the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dask prefers to execute tasks where memory can be freed, which ought to be depth-wise in your example. However, it also gives you parallelism; so the easiest way may be just to have one worker.

Indeed, the linear chains in the graph would make a good case for fuse. You can call optimise yourself (`dask.optimization.inline_functions`, `dask.optimization.fuse`, shouldn't need custom), or you could write a function which explicitly calls each sub-task in turn within a single task (`save(process(load(..)))`).

Comment: Graph ended up not looking like I thought in the graph tab so when I updated it did as you said and ran depth first, thanks!